# `updated_at` time doesn't reflect my time zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, timezone

I'm trying to get the `updated_at` timestamps in my app to reflect my time zone.  They display correctly locally, but when they're in `production` on Heroku they reflect standard UTC.  I've added this to my Heroku configuration:

`$ heroku config:add TZ=America/Minneapolis`

In my `application.rb` I've also added:

```
config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

The timestamps on Heroku still show UTC time, I'm UTC/GMT -5:00.  Anyone know what I'm missing or doing incorrectly?

---

### Update

---

When I display `entries` in my project, I include the timestamp `updated_at` at the bottom of each `entry`'s text.  The timestamps display the UTC time, I'd like them to display the time that I updated it in the Central time zone, just so the time isn't 5 hours ahead of when I did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was displaying the timestamps with `entry.updated_at.localtime.strftime('* %a, %b %-e, %Y @ %l:%M%p')`.  I think that having the `localtime` method in there had something to do with it.  I removed `localtime` and added `%Z` to the end of the `strftime` arguments to add the abbreviated timezone.  Now it's showing up how I wanted.  I'm not sure how `localtime` was affecting that, but removing it seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Updating to answer the updated question.

If the time zone for your app is always going to be 'Central', you can set the Time Zone for your ApplicationController

```
Time.zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

Comment: No, that just gives a string of the set timezone.

Comment: As reference to statement above: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-zone